# CakePHP, Rails respond_to equivalent

Tags: cakephp

What's the best way to output different types of responses f.ex xml, json, html, rss etc. in the same controller action, and how would I send the preferred content-type to the action?

Ex. rails URLs:

- /user/add.xml = XML output
- /user/add.js  = JS/JSON output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not really tried to achieve this I'm not too sure, but there is a chapter on this in the book, http://book.cakephp.org/view/174/Request-Handling which looks, at a skim, like it might cover what you need. It seems to revolve around processing the type of request.

Comment: RequestHandler works great with ajax, since it's xhr request. Seems like i have to specify $type in the controller and send this parameter as a GET.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are web services. Lots of resources online.

[ow-easy-are-web-services-in-cakephp-12-really-easy](http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2007/03/13/how-easy-are-web-services-in-cakephp-12-really-easy/)

[cakephp-and-restful-web-services](http://blog.accuweaver.com/2008/12/04/cakephp-and-restful-web-services/)